# what to plant after daffodil dies out

Tags: daffodils

I have a large fields with daffodils.  After they dies out, weeds grow in the field. I am thinking about what can I grow in between the daffodils while the daffodils is active or in the field after daffodils dies out.

I guess that I can just grow annuals in the fields after daffodil dies out? Of course there is a short period when the yellow foliage from daffodil is visible.  But that's OK to me, I am mainly concerned with weeds dominate the field in the summer and fall.

I was thinking of growing other perennials (which bloom in summer/fall) in between daffodil. But it looks like daffodil grow earlier and quite tall and will shield sunlight from the other perennials (which starts growing later). The field is densely populated withe daffodils.  When daffodils falls down to the ground, they will likely cover the other perennials, So growing other perennials in between daffodil may not be a good idea.

I don't want ground cover plants like hostas. It's just green plants.  I'd like colorful flowers.

So looks like my  option is to plant the seeds for annuals after daffodils is completely yellow and falls down to the ground. so I have to plant fast growing annuals.  The field is very large, buying annuals is too expensive. Start seedling in pots looks too much work.

My search yields these annuals:
Marigolds
Zinnia
4 o'clock
stock
sweet asylums

Ideally I'd like annuals that are fast growing from seeds, blooming in summer/fall, fragrant and deer/rabbit resistant.

Any better suggestions?

Thanks.

Comment: How densely planted are the daffodils? I'm referring to the spacing between where each clump of leaves rise from the ground? A photo showing the average spacing between clumps (with a ruler for scale) would be helpful in answering the question.